# FileSystemWatcher not firing events till PowerShell closes

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have a script (below) that watches a folder that the .ps1 script sits in.
When a file is created it fires a .bat file to do a job.

Initially it would run and close immediately.
So I added '''Start-Sleep -s 50'''

It works but it only triggers the .bat launch when the PowerShell window closes.

(As I don't know how long it will be till a file turns up in the folder, this is kind of useless).

Ideally I could do with the .bat file launching as soon as the new file is created, which in turn then closes the PowerShell window

```
$configFilePath = $PSScriptRoot
$filter = '*.*'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $configFilePath, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\log\Filelog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    Set-Location "$PSScriptRoot"
    Start-Process "$PSScriptRoot\PS_Run.bat"
}

Start-Sleep -s 50
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-6: "When the subscribed event is raised, it is added to the event queue in your session. To get events in the event queue, use the Get-Event cmdlet."

Comment: Thanks,
Would "Get-Event" replace "Register-ObjectEvent"?

Comment: No, it doesn't replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace Start-Sleep with:

```
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated
```

Then you need to add an exit command to your watcher like this:

```
Start-Process "$PSScriptRoot\PS_Run.bat"
exit
}
```

Since you cannot exit the console from the filewatcher, you can do this instead:

```
$configFilePath = $PSScriptRoot
$filter = '*.*'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $configFilePath, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
    Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\log\Filelog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    Set-Location "$PSScriptRoot"
    Start-Process "$PSScriptRoot\PS_Run.bat"
}
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Timeout 50 # or no of seconds before file shows up.
```

When run as a scheduled task, this will execute the bat file as soon as a new file is created and close the console when the timeout is reached.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
Works up to the Exit, Tried:
Exit,
Exit-PSSession, Exit-Hostprocess &
Close... The window stays open..

Comment: You are right. The file watcher cannot close the console. You could set a -TimeOut on the Wait-Event. That would exit the script once the execution has finished and the time has expired.

Comment: I'm new to PS. How would that look? Found a couple of things online to add -Timeout but I cant seem to get it to hold until the execution has finished.